# Find dropdown values on user control inside repeater asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, findcontrol

I am trying to access DropDownList selected value from user control which is placed inside Repeater's `ItemTemplate`.

```
string ddlBeneficiaryTeam2 = ((UserControl_TeamFilter)(rptBeneficiaries.FindControl("ucBeneficiaryTeam"))).TeamSelectedValue;
```

- rptBeneficiaries -Repeater control
- ucBeneficiaryTeam -User control
- ddlteam -DropDownList Name its in user control.

Comment: I need to access this ddlTeam seleted value here is the control ID :ctl00_cphMain_rptBeneficiaries_ctl00_ucBeneficiaryTeam_ddlTeam

Answer (score 0):

You can use FindControl to locate the correct Control by going up the control tree.

```
DropDownList drp = Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("WebUserControl1").FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
```

First you access the correct repeater item by an index and then by ID of the User Control and then the DropDownList inside the control.

Answer (score 0):

first divide this to two part
1-first in your **Usercontrol** create **public property** that represents value of your **DropDown**

```
public class UserControl_TeamFilter : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
   ....
   public string TeamSelectedValue
   {
       get { return ddlteam.SelectedValue; }
   }
   ...
```

2-now you just need to find and cast your **Usercontrol** in repeater item as below

```
(rptBeneficiaries.Items[i].FindControl("ucBeneficiaryTeam") as UserControl_TeamFilter).TeamSelectedValue
```